# Camel rest API for file download

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

Is there any camel restful web service example to provide file download as below api

```
@GET
@Path("/jar")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response downloadFile() {
    File file = new File("/home/user/Downloads/classes.jar");
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=classes.jar");
    return response.build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [Camel REST DSL](http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html) and [Content Enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) (specifically - `pollEnrich`).

An example implementation for your case could look like this:

```
// you can configure it as you want, it's just an example
restConfiguration().component("restlet").host("localhost").port(8081);

rest("/jar")
    .get()
    .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    .route()
    .routeId("downloadFile")
    .pollEnrich("file:/home/user/Downloads?fileName=classes.jar&noop=true")
    .setHeader("Content-Disposition", simple("attachment;filename=classes.jar"));
```

Please note, that if the file is not found in the specified path, `pollEnrich` will block until the file arrives. You can set a timeout in milliseconds by providing a second argument of type `long` to the call to `pollEnrich`.